# SceneKit: PhysicsWorld relative to body

Tags: ios, scenekit

I have a ship that everything is centered around and everything moves relative to it. It is a first person shooter. Right now when I fire, and the ship speeds up, it catches up to the bullets. I would like the physics world to move relative to the ship's speed so that the bullet is essentially unaffected by ship speed.

The physics engine is doing the right thing, but not the right thing for my game.

I have other elements that move relative to the ship as it moves, which move correctly now, so don't want make ship stationary and move everything else in world around it. I don't see a direct way to do this maybe there is an indirect way? Perhaps I can manually take over the positioning of the bullets. I would like to use the other parts of the physics engine for doing collisions etc so don't want to completely manually do it, but will if that is the only option.

Anyone else have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your bullets are receiving air friction. This is controlled by the physics bodies "damping" property.  A value of 1.0 will make it static without movement. A value of 0 will allow it to move continuously without ever stoping.  The default value is 0.1 as per the Apple documents. Assign your node like so to remove the damping(air friction)...

```
yourNode.physicsBody.damping = 0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I decided not to go with the physics system, it adds complexity that my game simply does not need. Without it I was able to make a lot of progress and in fact get it to do exactly what I describe above, just without the physics. Seems it is not the right tool for my project.